# How can I update 2 or more unique documents in mongoose db

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have 3 unique documents in mydb, I want to update each document using there unique keys that are generated randomly.

I tried updateMany() and update({multi:true}).  Using upadteMany() we can update the document that matches the query. Is there any way that I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

If I have the following documents:

```
doc1 : {
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 20
}

doc2 : {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Jane Smith',
  age: 22
}
```

I want the client to be able to pass me both docs in the same request for update. In this case maybe add an address to both docs.

Is there a way the I can send one update statement to mongo such that it updates both of the documents with the name values?

> the answer you provided is good.  but i modified that code and it looks like

```
      _id: { $in: [req.params.noteId,req.params.noteId,req.params.noteId]}
   }
   Note.updateMany(query,
       {$set:{
           lname: req.body.lname || "Untitled Note",
           age: req.body.age
       }}
, { new: true }
   )
```

this code is not working

Comment: Can You add Your Schema for More Details?

Comment: I updated my quetion u can see my schema now

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There are no errors in the coding i am just showing what i have done

Comment: I am Updated my question, Now u can see what i am really looking for.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the below code you can solve your problem . 
 //consider the following object to update

```
doc1 : {
  _id: 1,
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 20
}

doc2 : {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Jane Smith',
  age: 22
}
```

The below code will change the name of both the docs to `manjesha`

```
var criteria =  {
        _id : { $in : [ "1"  , "2"] }
}
userModel.update(criteria  , { name: "manjesha" }, { multi: true },function(err , found){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            res.send(found);
        }
});
// $in -The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.
```

This will work perfect on your problem .

Comment: I have updated the question above i am getting issuse.

Comment: Get back to you soon with answer

Comment: Sorry , will have a look on your problem by tomorrow morning , it time to leave therefore . @manjesha

Comment: `{ multi: true }` is not there in your query , try out adding that .  @manjesha

Comment: I using updateMany() , in this if we use `{ multi : true }` we get an callbak error

Comment: ``var query = {
     [ mongoose.Types.ObjectId]:
    {$in: [req.params.noteId,req.params.noteId,req.params.noteId]}}
    
    Note.update(query,
        {
            
            lname: req.body.lname || "Untitled Note",
            age: req.body.age
        },{multi:true}
    )``

Comment: Sir.. The above data i provided for that your code works fine. my point is how the client can update the document by selecting two or more _id's that selected by him randomly..

Comment: You can try one approach , from `client-side`  send `id` and assign that `id` in `var criteria`  . Make sure that `datatype` of all the `id` you inserted into  `var criteria` is same as mine code . @manjesha

Comment: As u said i am assinging them, for `findByIdAndUpdate()`  its working. I am confused how to assign multiple `id` to `var criteria`  . u can see my above comments how i assigning `id`

Comment: Why you dissagree my answeer . ? I was middle with my project . will get back to you soon . please  mark it as green . @manjesha

Comment: This is not the way of doing unaccepting the answer . I have solved your query and then you updated your question . Though i was going to solve your problem then also you unaccepted my answer . @manjesha

Comment: I can understand and i dont know how it happend. It was not intentionally, When you r free get back to me . thanku sir